# Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Tags: appium-ios

> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command:
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined.

I am getting the above error, while lauching appium on real device.

```
{
    "platformName": "iOS",
    "deviceName": "iPhoneX",
    "bundleId": "com.test.app",
    "platformVersion": "11.4",
    "udid": "XXX",
    "automationName": "XCUITest",
    "noReset": "true",
    "xcodeOrgId": "XXX",
    "xcodeSigningId": "XXX",
    "app": "/Users/sathya/android-sdks/platform-tools/test.app"
}
```

Comment: Where's your code and other related info?

Comment: @Paul, as you can see i added the desiredcapabilites for launching on the real device

Comment: Have you Googled the issue? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=appium+Encountered+internal+error+running+command%3A+TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+property+%27count%27+of+undefined&rlz=1C1GGRV_enGB770GB770&oq=appium+Encountered+internal+error+running+command%3A+TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+property+%27count%27+of+undefined&aqs=chrome..69i57.2293j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Appium version?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have googled to no avail

Answer (score 1):

This may come a bit late, but I have ran into this issue today. Typing into cmd

> adb devices

I got that the device is unauthorized

```
List of devices attached
RF8T20AG1EB     unauthorized
```

After revoking authorization, and toggling USB Debugging off/on, and then reconnecting the device, I was prompted by allow message.

After allowing the device, the list should show as:

```
List of devices attached
RF8T20AG1EB     device
```

Rerunning the test works normally now.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same error - Cannot read property 'count' of undefined.
Here are steps helped me resolved the error.

1. Stop and close all instances of Appium Inspector.
2. Restart Appium server.
3. Make sure that you don't run any Inspector window during your test execution.